# Intro to Stats: Finding mean waiting time between accidents

Tags: statistics

The number of traffic accidents at a certain intersection is thought to be well modeled by a Poisson process with a mean of 3.5 accidents per year.

Find the mean waiting time between accidents and
find the standard deviation of the waiting times between accidents.

I assumed $\mu$ = $\lambda$ and $\sigma$$^2$ = $\lambda$, but that didn't seem to work. I've been looking at multiple formulas, including the Poisson ones, and I can't figure out how to even begin to figure this out. I could use a step in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.5 accidents per year implies one accident per 1/3.5 years = 0.28 years. This is the mean waiting time between accidents.

> The variance of the waiting time will also be 0.28 years, meaning that the standard deviation is its square root, 0.535 years.

EDIT: I made an error. lambda = 3.5, so mean interarrival time is 1/lambda = 0.28 years; however, the variance of the interarrival time is 1/(lambda^2), meaning the standard deviation of the interarrival time is 0.28 years

Read more here: https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/weber/decs-430/Notes%20on%20the%20Poisson%20and%20exponential%20distributions.pdf